# jquery animate question

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am attempting to animate fireflies to fade in, pulsate and then fade out.
I am using the code below, but the final animate seems to fire before the pulsate effect.  if I remove the pulsate it works as well.  Ideas?

```
$('#fireflies').animate({'opacity':1}, 20000)
  .effect('pulsate', { times:6 }, 3500)
  .animate({'opacity':0}, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should chain these using callbacks.  That way, the next effect won't be queued until the previous effect has been completed.

```
$('#fireflies').animate({'opacity':1}, 20000, function() {
     $(this).effect('pulsate', { times:6 }, 3500, function() {
         $(this).animate({'opacity':0},20000);
     });
});
```